# Why does the Podcasts app stop playing when I change the audio device?

Tags: iphone, audio, podcasts.app

Whenever I change the audio device while using the Podcasts app it stops playing audio, without indicating that the podcast has stopped. For example, if I plug in headphones or turn on bluetooth (with a paired audio device), the playback just stops. I can still interact with the app, even selecting another podcast, but no playback.

Sometimes it will start playing again in a minute or so. Sometimes it stops "forever" (longer than I care to wait). I can force kill the app and restart it to get playback to continue immediately.

Any idea why this happens or how I can get it to behave properly?

---

I'm on iOS 7.1.1 now, but it's been happening since iOS 7.1.0 ish. I do remember the Podcast app working flawlessly at one point (probably 7.0.0).

Comment: what version of ios 7? also is this only one way or both ways, speaker to headphone, and vice verse

Comment: Seems to happen as soon as I change the audio playback device, in any direction. If I have headphones in and pull them out, playback stops like normal (seems to be a feature in case you yank your headphones by accident). But, in this case, even if I hit play again, it doesn't. I can put the headphones back in and it still doesn't play back.

Comment: last question, can you play something with another app to see

Comment: I don't have any music or videos on my device, but I can try with a streaming radio app or a website or something. Thanks.